# Excel Worksheet Name Not Recognized

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I have a C# application that I use to create an excel file for import into another application. The problem is, the application that accepts the imports is reporting that the 'tables' its looking for do not exist. The tables are the respective sheets which I name in C# as follows:

```
worksheet1 = workbook.Sheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)worksheet1;
worksheet1.Name = "Pay";
```

From my research, renaming the sheet this way does not fully rename the sheet. any ideas on this?

Comment: Are you also renaming workbook.Sheets[0]?  Any other code you can provide?  Do you have an image of a working excel doc?

Comment: Can you more clearly state the problem?  You have provided code which appears to be adequate for renaming a sheet.  That right?  If so, what is the other side of this... the application that is reporting the error?  It is true in VBA there are `Worksheet` objects for each sheet that have there own names, but is that really what the other application is looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The issues was that the application was looking for named ranges as opposed to the actual sheet names.Thanks all!